# How to add a new checkbox when I click a button?

Tags: android, button, checkbox

[checkbox should be created in red zone when button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l9b7.png)

I have tried this:

```
public void newcheckbox() {
  LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);

  CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
  checkBox.setText(""+ETnewcheckbox.getText().toString());
  my_layout.addView(checkBox);
}
```

Comment: what is your exact issue

Comment: Tried it? Well done!

Comment: app is crashing when is click on that button

Comment: than share your crash log with question and whole activity code

Comment: check out the image in  edited question

Answer (score 0):

in your XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="8dp"
     android:paddingEnd="16dp"
     android:paddingStart="16dp"
     android:paddingTop="8dp">

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btCalculator"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="click" />

           <CheckBox
               android:id="@+id/cbVar"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:visibility="gone" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

in your Java Class:
before OnCreate:

```
Button btCalculator;
CheckBox cbVar;
```

in OnCreate:

```
cbVar= findViewById(R.id.cbVar);

btCalculator = findViewById(R.id.btCalculator);

btCalculator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cbVar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: actually i want to add as many checkboxes as the user want. When user inputs Text in EditText, new checkbox with that text should be added to the view

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Recycleview`.
Create a basic model for your checkbox like

```
class CheckboxModel{
 private  String text;
 private  boolean value;
...
}
```

you should create your CheckboxAdapter with ViewHolder and update your adapter when user click the button.
`adapter.setItems(list);` (Do not forget to tell that notifyDataSetChanged)

Comment: i'm a noob.can you give me the code...